# How to keep local versioned files in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I have a config file that is versioned, lets call it Web.Config. I want to be able to keep the original versioned file in the repo as a template, but maintain my locally modified version through pulls, fetches, merges, etc. Is this possible in Mercurial?

Comment: I'm not sure what "as a template" means to you, but this sounds like something every version control system does. When you want the original version, you checkout the original version. When you want version 'n', you checkout version 'n'.

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked/answered here quite often, but I'll bite:

The way to do this is to keep a version in the repository that's a template and keep your actual modified version local-only and listed in .hgignore.  For example keep the file `app.config.sample` in the repo and have your build / launch scripts look for `app.config`, which is listed in the `.hgignore`.  If you want to get fancy you can even have your launch/build scripts copy the sample file to the actual file if it doesn't exist when run.

In short, there is no *good* way to have a file both tracked (added) and untracked (changes aren't committed) at the same time unless you want to do it manually using commands like `hg commit -I app.config`, which even with aliases, you'll eventually forget.

Comment: "In short, there is no way to have a file both tracked (added) and untracked (changes aren't committed) at the same time" - WRONG, you FAIL. I know at least **two ways to have**

Comment: You're right.  I shoul've said there's "no good way".  Your two ways suck, because they cause more problems than they solve, but if you want to join us in #mercurial and help with the flood of "I accidentally pushed my password-containing config branch" and "mq ate my lunch" help requests I'll see you there.  I'll be the guy cleaning up others' bitdroppings from the bad advice in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- Create local-only customized config in MQ-patch (rename or copy template, apply needed changes to local config), apply patch for local work, unapply before push (or use secure phase for patches and they will not be published even if applied)
- Build customized local config in local branch (ordinary named branch, which must be **never merged to default**, you merge only default *to local branch*) and always use `push -b default` (directly or as alias-command): because local branch haven't ancestors for default's head, it will not be pushed